# find two matrices A and B such that $A^2 -BA-AB+B^2 = O_{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone please explain this question to me

Question : Construct a $2\times 2$ matrix A and B with A different from B and neither A = $O_{2\times 2}$ nor $B = O_{2\times 2}$ such that $A^2 - BA - AB + B^2 = O_{2\times 2}$

Attempt: I found a matrix A such such that $a_{11} = 0$, $a_{12} = 0$, $a_{21} =1$, and $a_{22} = 0$ but I couldn't find a second matrix B that will respect the given condition

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $A^2-BA-AB+B^2=(A-B)^2$.

Comment: A matrix which becomes 0 after a certain number of powers is called "nilpotent". This might be helpful if you.

Comment: i tried to construct two nilpotents matrices, bu their product is different from 0.

Comment: Then you are working too hard.  You only need to find one nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 10):

$A^2 - AB - BA + B^2 = (A-B)^2 = O$

Find a matrix $M$ such that $M^2 = O$

How about $M = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Now find chose $A, B$ such that $(A-B) = M$

Comment: excuse me, but the product of two matrices AB is different from the product of BA. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: @patriciajade  Absolutely true, but is that relevant?